# What does this line mean?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am a beginner at PHP. I would like to know what line 47 in [this](https://github.com/khalid-hussain/JSPHP1/blob/master/Ch%2005/updated/kickstart/includes/posts.php) file, means:

`$posts[$key]['comments'] = $this->comments->commentNumber($post['id']);`

I'm going through the book called 'Jump Start PHP' from SitePoint and I don't fully comprehend this line. Another problem which adds to the lack of understand is the missing schema which is not provided by the book.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you know how `$this.comments.commentNumber($post['id']);` would work?

Comment: Simple: It's an assignment! It's assigning a function call of an object with 1 argument into an array index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->comments
```

is instantiated at line 20, in the class constructor for class Posts. Basically, a new instance of "Comments" class is instantiated and set to $this->comments.

When you call:

```
$posts[$key]['comments'] = $this->comments->commentNumber($post['id']);
```

it is calling line 90 -- the commentNumber method of class Comments. The method accepts an ID of a post and returns the number of comments for that post.

The purpose of this line and its associated loop is to cycle through all of the posts and get the number of comments for each. Once the loop completes, the array $posts will 
contain all the information about the posts (one post per array index) including the number of comments.

Comment: Exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$this->comments` is the object of **class Comments** which contains a method/function named **commentNumber**

```
$posts[$key]['comments'] = $this->comments->commentNumber($post['id']);
```

In this statement,  commentNumber functions is called on the object of class Comments and assign the return value to the variable $post at index $key.

Comment: I'm sorry I was not more specific. In the function getPosts(), the first loop gets all posts but what is the loop with this line for?

Comment: in the constructor of class Posts $this->comments is set to the instance of class Comments
See line 20